# Why does Python's queue.Queue.get() permit returning early from timeouts?

Tags: python, real-time

UPDATE: This question is based on a faulty mental model of how Queue.get() was actually behaving, which was caused by some slightly ambiguous documentation but mainly by a buggy, hand-rolled implementation of `timedelta.total_seconds()`. I discovered this bug when trying to prove that the original answers where incorrect. Now that `timedelta.total_seconds()` is provided by Python (since 2.7), I will move to use that.

Sorry for the confusion.

---

This isn't a "Why does my code not run?" question, but a "What is the motivation behind this design decision?"

Since 2.3, Python's queue module contains a Queue class with a get method, that takes a timeout parameter. Here's the section from the manual:

> `Queue.get([block[, timeout]])`
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks ***at most*** timeout seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within that time. [...]

(Emphasis mine)

Note that it may raise an Empty exception *even if it hasn't reached the timeout*. In fact, I am seeing that behaviour on Ubuntu (but not Windows). It is bailing just a little early and it has had minor consequences on my code - I can code around it though.

Most blocking timeouts take a *minimum* timeout, which makes sense on a non-real-time OS, including Windows and Linux. There is no guarantee that the OS will context switch to your process or thread by any given deadline.

However, this one takes a *maximum* timeout. Can anyone explain how this design decision might make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the documentation.  It isn't saying it might raise the `Empty` exception after less than `timeout` seconds, it is saying it will block for at most `timeout` seconds.  It might block for less than that, if it can satisfy the `get`.

I realize you are saying you see it raising `Empty` early, but honestly, that sounds like either a bug, or that you are relying on more accuracy than the system can provide.  (It does seem as though, to obey the exact wording of the specification, an implementation should round `timeout` *down* to the resolution of its timer rather than up as you seem to desire.)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're doing real-time programming, a correct program must assume any timeout value is a guidance anyway, so it does not matter on which side you error. Note that `queue` **does** wait for **at least** the timeout if the queue stays empty (Confirmed by a look in the code which is basically a loop that exits if `remaining` (time) is less than 0). It returns earlier if an item is put into the queue in the meantime, though.

You're expecting this behavior:

```
[0] (Thread) A calls Queue.get(True, 10)
[0] B waits 9 seconds
[9] B does something on X
[11] A destroys X
```

But a valid schedule would be as well:

```
[0] (Thread) A calls Queue.get(True, 10)
[0] B waits 9 seconds
[9] Operating system is busy for 2 seconds
[11] A gets picked by the OS, destroys X    
[12] B does something on X
```

You need to fix the program to work independent of the actual timing of which thread is picked when.

Comment: +1 for checking the code behind Queue.Queue. That shook my confidence in my position. I should have done that myself. However, while I was clearly confused, this wasn't the confusion I was having. I was alleging that Thread A was waking up at [9.999] with nothing in the queue. I see now that I was sleeping for 9.999 rather than 10, due to an implementation bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a bug in **Queue.get**, at least in python 2.6.6.
On posix a **queue.get(timeout=1)** seems to exit (raising the Empty exception) almost immediately, whereas **queue.get(timeout=2)** is working fine.

I was using a single queue with concurrent threads **get**ing on it...